# How to type non-italic text in math mode as in the figure?

Tags: math-mode, typefaces

I want to know how I can type non-italic text in math mode like the "Prime" text in the following figure.[image]

In addition, the font of "Prime" is different from that of the main text. I want this requirement to be satisfied as well. What command can I use in the math mode to achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Please add a brief compilable example, showing what you have tried already.  Begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.  Then someone can provide an answer in context.

Comment: `\mathsf{Prime}`.

Comment: If Prime(*n*) should be an operator like ln(*n*) or sin(*n*), IMHO it would be better to not force sans-serif but define a new operator using `\DeclareMathOperator{\Prime}{Prime}`. See, e.g., section 5.1 of the `amsmath` manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to typeset the (math) word "Prime", using a sans-serif font, depends in part on whether you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document.

- If that's the case, then `\newcommand\Prime{\mathsf{Prime}}` is the easiest way to go.
- If, in contrast, you use either LuaLaTeX of XeLaTeX, it's preferable to load the [unicode-math](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) package -- which you might already be doing -- and to define `\Prime` via `\newcommand\Prime{\symsf{Prime}}`.

The following code shown below contains a conditional to handle the chore of appropriately defining `\Prime` automatically, depending on which TeX engine is in use.

[image]

(Observe that I've deliberately deviated from the appearance of the displayed formula in the OP's screenshot. There's simply no need to be so loose about typesetting math-y material.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,mathtools}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\usepackage{iftex} % for '\ifpdftex' conditional
\ifpdftex % pdfLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \newcommand\Prime{\mathsf{Prime}}
\else % either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is in use
   \usepackage{unicode-math} % for '\symsf' macro
   \newcommand\Prime{\symsf{Prime}}
\fi

\begin{document}
\setcounter{question}{4} % just for this example

\begin{question}
For an integer $n\geqslant 2$, let $\Prime(n)$ be the set of all prime numbers less than or equal to $n$. Prove that for every integer $n\geqslant 2$, 
\[
\prod_{\mathclap{p\in\Prime(n)}}p\leqslant 4^{n-1}
\]
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It should be `\mathsf` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\mathsf`, but with a twist: define a general command for such objects, so if you change your mind later, you don't need to chase in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fset}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
\newcommand{\Prime}{\fset{Prime}}

\begin{document}

\[
\prod_{p\in\Prime(n)} \mspace{-12mu} p \le 4^{n-1}
\]

\end{document}
```

The negative spacing improves the readability.

[image]

**Note** Despite others suggest switching to `\symsf` when `unicode-math` is used, I don't recommend it.

Look at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathsf{Effiflefi}\ne\symsf{Effiflefi}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the case of “Prime”, the differences are negligible, but ligatures *should* be honored in such cases, because you're typesetting a *word*, not a product of variables that happen to be denoted with sans serif type.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\text{}` with whatever text you want "normal" inside the curly braces.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `\text` will follow the style of the surrounding material, so if this were in a theorem, it would be set in text italic.  Better to use `\textup` which will force an upright style.

Comment: Given the OP's specific query and associated screenshot, you should be recommending `\textsf{}`, not just `\text{}`.